# Send email via exim4 using port 587

Tags: email, exim

0

I have configured exim4 and am trying to send out emails using port 587 and the email is being sent but on the mail server it show connecting at port 25. I am using:

echo "Subject:Hello All" | sendmail -v  -port 587 shaheena.kazi@gmail.com

T: remote_smtp for shaheena.kazi@gmail.com
Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4004:c08::1a]:25 ... LOG: MAIN
(Not pasting the entire output of the log here)

+++++++++++++++++++++ I wanted to check why the connection goes to port 25 as shown below---- """Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4004:c08::1a]:25 ... LOG: MAIN""""

I want all my email to connect on port 587 as I have requested for port 587. I have tried most of the settings shown online in the exim4 config file. But still it connects on 25. Links that I followed but no luck : https://www.fyzix.net/index.php?title=Installing_and_Configuring_Exim4_for_Gmail_SMTP_Relay and https://logs.paulooi.com/enable-smtp-port-587-on-exim.php

Also, any mail server I use... it connects to port 25..

Could anyone help me here ?

Comment: https://www.warpconduit.net/2016/05/14/configuring-exim-authenticated-smtp-relay-gmail-centos/

Comment: What you are looking for is "relay email via gmail with exim4". The link above should guide you throu it.

Comment: Or if you decide to use postfix, which is much easier (in my opinion) to use: https://blogs.linux.pizza/postfix-relay-emails-via-a-another-mailserver-with-authentication-and

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible.

Mail servers talk to each other on port 25. You cannot change this.

You have to use port 25 if you want other servers to be able to talk to it.

Answer (score 1):

Port 587,This is the default mail submission port, so it should only be used for submissions (i.e., mail client to mail server)

while SMTP (Port 25) is the protocol, or set of rules for formatting data, that helps emails travel across the Internet. It transfers emails from mail server to mail server until they reach their final destination.